# confusion about creating a class array

Tags: java

Suppose I have two classes in a Java Package:

`Class1.java` and `Class2.java`

So, if in `Class1.java`, I do the following:

```
public Class2[] QR;

public static int x = 10;
```

Then later on somewhere in the code:

```
QR = new Class2[x];
```

So basically, I will be passing value 10 to class2 , right? Please correct me if I have not understood it properly.

Comment: `I will be passing value 10 to class2`. No. The value 10 will be used in the array creation expression. It is unrelated to `Class2`.

Comment: You will be creating an Array which can hold (references to) 10 Class2 instances.

Comment: @WhoAmI That comment is currently the best answer here.  I will upvote it if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you are not passing 10 to the value of class2.
You are making an array of class2 whose size is 10.

**Detail explaination:**

`public Class2[] QR;`

In this statement you are saying, Hey i want to hold some objects of Class2 in an array whose name is QR.
(Till now you have not specified how many objects you want to keep in QR, so initialization of array is not done yet)

`QR = new Class2[x];`

Here you are saying, now i know how many (x many items) objects i will keep in QR, so allocate memory( via new keyword) to QR.

So basically you have just initialized the array with the number of items you will keep in array, i.e you have specified the size of array.

Now class2 object will reside at some index in the QR (index 0 to 9).
`Class2 c = QR[0]; // for example`

Answer (score 3):

```
QR = new Class2[x];
```

This creates a Class2 array of size 10.

Comment: In order to initialize each element of the Class2 array, iterate over it with a for loop. Each element (Example QR[0]) is a Class2 Object, so iterate over it and set each one to a new Class2 .

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of `Class2` and initialize it as:

```
public Class2[] QR;  // Declare the array
public static int x = 10;
QR = new Class2[x];  // Allocate for 10 instances memory 

// Now create the and init the instances
for (int i=0 ; i<QR.lenght ; i++) {
   QR[i] = new Class2();  // Call the constructor
}
```